# How to create a dict-of-dicts from a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

How do I create a dictionary inside a dictionary in python with three different values, where `date` is a key to the first dictionary, second dict (with `city` is a key and quantity of rain is value) and second dictionary is the value of the first.

```
import csv

def read_data(file):
    open('file', 'r') as f:
        r = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')
        s = {}
        for row in r:
            row = vrstica[a][b]
            while a == 0 and b > 0:
                row = int(key1)
            while row == row[0]:
                row = key2
            else:
                row = value

        key1 = dict((key2,value) for row in reader)
        s = dict(key1)

    return s
```

Comment: You are overwriting `row` in the loop.

Comment: Please [edit] your question an describe what is wrong (or what do you want to know).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the same example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
1/1/2018    boston  5
1/1/2018    chicago 7
1/2/2018    boston  9
1/2/2018    chicago 3'''

file = pd.compat.StringIO(data) # change to path

df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\s+', header=None, names=list('ABC'))

# Use pandas and groupby
df.groupby(df.A)['B','C'].apply(lambda x: x.set_index('B')['C'].to_dict()).to_dict()
```

And you get

```
{'1/1/2018': {'boston': 5, 'chicago': 7},
 '1/2/2018': {'boston': 9, 'chicago': 3}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting rain value once a day for each city, you can do it as below. If you are getting multiple times within a day, you may need a `list` to hold values of rain data for each city.

Hope this helps.

```
s = {}
with open(csvfile, 'r') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')    
    for row in r:
        key = row[0]
        if not key in s:
            s[row[0]]={row[1]:row[2]}
        else:
            s[row[0]].update({row[1]:row[2]})
```

**csvdata**

```
1/1/2018    boston  5
1/1/2018    chicago 7
1/2/2018    boston  9
1/2/2018    chicago 3
```

**Dictionary content**

```
>>> s
{'1/1/2018': {'boston': '5', 'chicago': '7'}, '1/2/2018': {'boston': '9', 'chicago': '3'}}
```